# .net core 3.0 Constructor parameter problem

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core-3.0

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'userRoleService' of 'AuthorizeUserAttribute.AuthorizeUserAttribute(string, IUserRoleService, IModuleService, IUserService)'

AuthorizationController.cs

```
[AuthorizeUserAttribute("User.Edit")]
public ActionResult UserAuthorizationEdit()
```

AuthorizeUserAttribute.cs

```
public string Action { get; set; }
private IUserRoleService _userRoleService;
private IModuleService _moduleService;
private IUserService _userService;

public AuthorizeUserAttribute(IUserRoleService userRoleService, IModuleService moduleService, IUserService userService)
{

    _userRoleService = userRoleService;
    _moduleService = moduleService;
    _userService = userService;
}
```

When I try to add constructor,controller side says write constructor as a parameter. How Can i change interface to a constructor

Comment: By "How Can i change interface to a constructor" do you mean how do you change the constructor? Just edit it... You have four required parameters but only supply one, either make them optional or provide all parameters.

Comment: I suspect you'll need to redesign your system - it doesn't make much sense for an attribute to accept interfaces, given that the arguments have to be compile-time constants.

Comment: In AuthorizationController, where you put the attribute, you haven't given all the parameters set in the attribute class.

Comment: What are you trying to create?Do you want to create a custom authorize filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to uses interfaces via class constructor using DI,you need to pass the parameter with the same type from custom attribute on controller side.

To avoid doing that, you could register your interfaces as services and get them using below code without constructor injection.For example:

1.Interface

```
public interface IUserRoleService
{
    List<string> GetValues();
}

public class UserRoleService : IUserRoleService
{
    private List<string> _privateList = new List<string>();

    public List<string> GetValues()
    {
        _privateList.Add("test");
        return _privateList;
    }
}
```

2.In startup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddSingleton<IUserRoleService, UserRoleService>();
}
```

3.Custom Authorization Attribute

```
public class AuthorizeUserAttribute:AuthorizeAttribute, IAsyncAuthorizationFilter
{
    public string Action { get; set; }

    public AuthorizeUserAttribute(string action)
    {
        Action = action;       
    }
    public async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext authorizationFilterContext)
    {
        var x = authorizationFilterContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IUserRoleService>();
        var y = x.GetValues();
    }
}
```

4.Action

```
[AuthorizeUserAttribute("User.Edit")]
public ActionResult UserAuthorizationEdit()
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use

```
[TypeFileter(typeof(AuthorizeUser),Arguments = new object[] { "User.Edit" }))]
public ActionResult UserAuthorizationEdit(int userId, 
             RoleRegisterDto authorizationModel)
```

in order to dependency injection can inject your services.